# How to interrupt the current touch on my view?

Tags: android, listview, touch, motionevent

Iam using a `ListView`. when user starts dragging at a particular point i want to roll the list to a position,At that time user doesn't trigger `ACTION_UP`. since he is still on the same touch path.

> Eg user starts dragging from position 5 and drags up to 200 i will restore list to some point but the touch continues from 200 without calling ACTION_DOWN.

So how can we call the `ACTION_UP` through code or `interrupt` the touch path.

Comment: if you are saying position 5 into 200 scroll down,then app start another activity and after go to Listview it should start from position 200 ?

Comment: sorry , there is no other activity ,iam reloading same listview here itself

Comment: So then you can store last start and end positions in data file.How about that ?

Comment: you didint get my question.. read it carefully, anyway thanks for trying to help